# Bootstrap modal form won't close on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, csv, bootstrap-modal

I'm having trouble with closing the modal when clicking the sign in button. Currently the Modal form will open up as soon as the page loads in. If I use data-dismiss="modal" in the submit button, my form doesn't record the input values into the csv file. Without the data-dismiss, the modal will continue to open unless I click the x in the top corner or click outside the modal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$error = '';
$name = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 if(empty($_POST["name"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
  }
 }
 if($error == '')
 {
  $file_open = fopen("results.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("results.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
  $form_data = array(
   'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
   'name'  => $name
  );
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
  $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
  $name = '';
 }
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('#submit').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Coding
    $('#myModal').modal('hide'); //or  $('#IDModal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Check In to Receive Credit</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Sign In</p>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```